# InputStream: int / long parameters mixing

Tags: java, inputstream

Loooking at **InputStream** we can find several methods:

```
public abstract int read() throws IOException;
public int read(byte b[]) throws IOException;
public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException
public long skip(long n) throws IOException
public int available() throws IOException
public synchronized void mark(int readlimit)
```

All methods except **skip()** deal with **int** parameter. Only method **skip()** accepts **long** parameter. What is the point of making this parameter of type **long** not **int**? It seems uncomfortable when extending from **InputStream** and making your own implementation.

Comment: That the other methods accept `int` is quite obvious: you can't read more then "max int" anyway. And why should skip be limited to `int`? What if you want to skip 900000000000 characters/byte? Skip multiple times? There was no point for this arbitrary constraint, thus they used `long`.

Comment: If it would've been `int` you could only skip 2 GiB with long you can work with much bigger streams.

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood the purposes of the other parameters.

The `long` parameter to `skip()` refers to an offset *within the file*, which can be as big as the file system can handle.

The `int` parameters for `offset` and `length` refer to offsets within, or lengths of, *arrays,* which can't be bigger than an `int` by virtue of the language design.

Ditto the `readLimit` of `mark()`.

The `int` return value of `available()` (a) isn't reliable anyway, (b) refers to the amount of data in a memory buffer, which is an array as above, and (c) wouldn't serve any practical use by being a `long`.